# Linux Change directory shortcut

Tags: linux, unix

I am using Bourne shell in Linux and I am trying to create a shortcut in my .profile to quickly jump between subdirectories.

I want to create a shortcut "cds" jump from the first directory to the 2nd below. These are just sample directories for his example.

/web/site/dev1/css 
/web/site/test1/css

Usage:  cds dev1 test1

```
cds() {
   echo `pwd` | sed -e "s/$1/$2/g"
   cd `pwd` | sed -e "s/$1/$2/g"
   pwd
}
```

The echo works but the cd line does not. Can you tell me why it does not work and how to get it to work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, when you do

```
   echo `pwd` | sed -e "s/$1/$2/g"
```

the output from `echo` is being piped into `sed` and the change is made. `sed` will print its output to the standard output.

However, `cd` doesn't write anything to the output, so you're `cd`ing to the current directory (`pwd`) and then piping the (empty) output into sed to replace the directory. Instead, you can call `cd` with the argument of the output of `pwd` piped through `sed`.

Here is the code you want instead:

```
cds() {        
  cd $(pwd | sed -e "s/$1/$2/g")
  pwd
}
```

First, this evaluates the code inside the `$()`, namely `pwd | sed -e "s/$1/$2/g"`. `pwd` prints the current path to stdout, and sed replaces the part of the path given by the arguments. So `$(pwd | sed -e "s/$1/$2/g"` evaluates to the new directory. Then, `cd` goes to that directory.

Comment: Thank you for the lesson as well as the answer. It works and I now I know why.